# IOS Swift Kingfisher Resize processor result blurry image

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I'm developing an app using Kingfisher library to load image from ulr and display in `CollectionViewCell`. I'm trying to resize the image to fit the `Contentview` of `CollectionViewCell`.

I have tried `ResizeProcessor` and `ScaleFactor` from the library but the result image seem `blur`. My implementation is below (function is call in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`)

```
let url = photo.flickrImageURL("m")
        let size = contentView.frame.size
        print("size is \(size.debugDescription)")
        let resizeProcessor = ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: size, mode: .aspectFit)
        self.flickrPhoto.kf.setImage(with: url, options: [.backgroundDecode,.processor(resizeProcessor), .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),.cacheOriginalImage])
```

Is there anything that I did wrong? The quality of `images` seem very blur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set `referenceSize` to size of `imageView` instead of `contentView`. As size of your `contentView` will be bigger than your `imageView`

Change your code with below code:

```
let size = self.flickrPhoto.frame.size
```

**UPDATED**

Just found that `ResizingImageProcessor` works on pixel instead of points so you need to multiply scale into image size like below:

```
let resizingProcessor = ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: CGSize(width: self.flickrPhoto.frame.size.width * UIScreen.main.scale, height: self.flickrPhoto.frame.size.height * UIScreen.main.scale))
```

Comment: thanks i have changed the size but seem result image is still blur even if tried directly "self.flickrPhoto.kf.setImage(with: url!)". It might be because of the library itself

Comment: Thanks let me check the result image. Does the .scaleFactor in The option array make any different?

Comment: Thanks. It seems improve the quality. Does the .scaleFactor in options make any difference?

Comment: Actually .scaleFactor should work similar to what we have did. It might issue in Kingfisher.

Comment: Thank. anyway to check the quality and dimension of our resize image compare to  original image?

Comment: You can do that in preview app by saving both(Original and Resized) images in MacOS. you will get multiple options in Tools>Adjust Size