# SwiftUI Kingfisher blurry Image on resize

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, kingfisher

In SwiftUI I’m using `Kingfisher` dependency for image download / cashing & have a following issue, when image resized it becomes low quality and blurry.

Here’s my implementation:

```
struct IconView: View {
    
    let frame: CGFloat
    let url: String
    let iconPath: String

    var body: some View {
        if !iconPath.isEmpty {
            KFImage(URL(string: "\(url)\(iconPath)"))
                .placeholder {
                    Circle().fill(Color.primaryBackground)
                        .frame(width: frame, height: frame)
                }
                .setProcessor(ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: CGSize(width: frame , height: frame), mode: .aspectFit))
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone suggest right implementation? How to not destroy image quality.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the resized image?

Comment: Original Image is 256x256 and resized 30x30

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem, issue here is that `Kingfisher` calculates image size in pixels rather than points in `ResizingImageProcessor`, so you have to multiply image size to device scale factor.

Useful discussions:
[IOS Swift Kingfisher Resize processor result blurry image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885861/ios-swift-kingfisher-resize-processor-result-blurry-image) &
[ResizingImageProcessor return a low quality image](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/689)

```
struct IconView: View {
    
    let frame: CGFloat
    let url: String
    let iconPath: String

    var body: some View {
        if !iconPath.isEmpty {
            KFImage(URL(string: "\(url)\(iconPath)"))
                .placeholder {
                    Circle().fill(Color.primaryBackground)
                        .frame(width: frame, height: frame)
                }
                .resizable()
                .setProcessor(ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: CGSize(width: frame * scale, height: frame * scale), mode: .aspectFit))
                .frame(width: frame, height: frame)
        }
    }
    
    private var scale: CGFloat {
        UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```